# how to add exception in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have following in htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?abcdef.com$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.xyz.org.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but i want to add an exception that :

```
abcdef.com/dir/index.php?amount=&option=true
```

shouldn't get redirected if option=true

if option is anyother value it should redirect using htaccess only.
Is it possible to do this with htaccess? As i only want to use htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !option=true
RewriteRule ...
```

which means if your request's query string does not contain the string `option=true`, it is ok to redirect