# .htaccess file redirect to dynamic page

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ location.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```

to redirect all `.html` page requests via a dynamic page - `location.php`.

How I can add exceptions to allow 2 or 3 pages to not be affected by this rule eg. index.html aboutus.html etc. thanks.

Comment: I think that this will answer your question : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111624/how-to-add-exception-in-htaccess][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111624/how-to-add-exception-in-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Place these lines at the top of your .htaccess file to skip to existing files and directories if they exist. If not, proccess our other rules as usual.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index|aboutus|contact)\.html$ [NC=
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ /location.php?cmd=$1 [L]
```